# How to plot an ellipse from eigenvalues and eigenvectors in R?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, matrix, matrix-decomposition, geometry

Could someone come up with *R* code to plot an ellipse from the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors of the following matrix 
$$
\mathbf{A} = \left(
\begin{array} {cc}
2.2 & 0.4\\
0.4 & 2.8
\end{array} \right)
$$

Comment: This is a FAQ and, even though it is `R`-oriented, the answers are applicable to all statistical computing.  Therefore I have reopened this question.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81285/appropriate-measure-to-find-smallest-covariance-matrix/385902#385902

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could extract the eigenvectors and -values via `eigen(A)`. However, it's simpler to use the Cholesky decomposition. Note that when plotting confidence ellipses for data, the ellipse-axes are usually scaled to have length = square-root of the corresponding eigenvalues, and this is what the Cholesky decomposition gives.

```
ctr    <- c(0, 0)                               # data centroid -> colMeans(dataMatrix)
A      <- matrix(c(2.2, 0.4, 0.4, 2.8), nrow=2) # covariance matrix -> cov(dataMatrix)
RR     <- chol(A)                               # Cholesky decomposition
angles <- seq(0, 2*pi, length.out=200)          # angles for ellipse
ell    <- 1 * cbind(cos(angles), sin(angles)) %*% RR  # ellipse scaled with factor 1
ellCtr <- sweep(ell, 2, ctr, "+")               # center ellipse to the data centroid
plot(ellCtr, type="l", lwd=2, asp=1)            # plot ellipse
points(ctr[1], ctr[2], pch=4, lwd=2)            # plot data centroid

library(car)  # verify with car's ellipse() function
ellipse(c(0, 0), shape=A, radius=0.98, col="red", lty=2)
```

Edit: in order to plot the eigenvectors as well, you have to use the more complicated approach. This is equivalent to suncoolsu's answer, it just uses matrix notation to shorten the code.

```
eigVal  <- eigen(A)$values
eigVec  <- eigen(A)$vectors
eigScl  <- eigVec %*% diag(sqrt(eigVal))  # scale eigenvectors to length = square-root
xMat    <- rbind(ctr[1] + eigScl[1, ], ctr[1] - eigScl[1, ])
yMat    <- rbind(ctr[2] + eigScl[2, ], ctr[2] - eigScl[2, ])
ellBase <- cbind(sqrt(eigVal[1])*cos(angles), sqrt(eigVal[2])*sin(angles)) # normal ellipse
ellRot  <- eigVec %*% t(ellBase)                                          # rotated ellipse
plot((ellRot+ctr)[1, ], (ellRot+ctr)[2, ], asp=1, type="l", lwd=2)
matlines(xMat, yMat, lty=1, lwd=2, col="green")
points(ctr[1], ctr[2], pch=4, col="red", lwd=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Would you mind to plot the eigenvalues and eigenvectors on this ellipse? Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 I edited my answer to show the eigenvectors as the ellipse's axes. Half the axes' length equals the square-root of the corresponding eigenvectors.

Answer (score 9):

I think this is the R code that you want. I borrowed the R-code from this [thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-October/114652.html) on the r-mailing list. The idea basically is: the major and minor half-diameters are the two eigen values and you rotate the ellipse by the amount of angle between the first eigen vector and the x-axis

```
mat <- matrix(c(2.2, 0.4, 0.4, 2.8), 2, 2)
eigens <- eigen(mat)
evs <- sqrt(eigens$values)
evecs <- eigens$vectors

a <- evs[1]
b <- evs[2]
x0 <- 0
y0 <- 0
alpha <- atan(evecs[ , 1][2] / evecs[ , 1][1])
theta <- seq(0, 2 * pi, length=(1000))

x <- x0 + a * cos(theta) * cos(alpha) - b * sin(theta) * sin(alpha)
y <- y0 + a * cos(theta) * sin(alpha) + b * sin(theta) * cos(alpha)


png("graph.png")
plot(x, y, type = "l", main = expression("x = a cos " * theta * " + " * x[0] * " and y = b sin " * theta * " + " * y[0]), asp = 1)
arrows(0, 0, a * evecs[ , 1][2], a * evecs[ , 1][2])
arrows(0, 0, b * evecs[ , 2][3], b * evecs[ , 2][2])
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: please feel free to correct me. I don't think the eigen vecs are perpendicular (they must be in theory; may be I am plotting something wrong?).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This ellipse looks nice but something is missing there. I tried your given code with this matrix 
$\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A} = \left(
\begin{array} {cc}
1 & -5\\
-5 & 1
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation*}$ and it gave correct ellipse. I'm wondering why it is not providing the correct ellipse for different variances in the matrix. Any comment!

Comment: Just set `asp=1` to have an aspect ratio of 1 and perpendicular arrows. Changing your code to `evs <- sqrt(eigens$values)` gives the same ellipse as my answer.

Comment: @MYaseen208 Your new matrix is not positive definite: it has negative eigenvalues and isn't a possible covariance matrix. I don't know what ellipse to draw in that case.

Comment: @caracal thanks! ... yeah -- I missed the sqrt part!