# is the difference of two positive definite matrices also positive definite?

Tags: matrix, matrix-decomposition

If one subtracts one positive definite matrix from another, will the result still be positive definite, or not? How can one prove this？

Comment: The one-by-one matrices $(1)$ and $(2)$ are positive-definite.  What about the matrix $(1)-(2)=(-1)$?

Comment: Much more elegant via Erdös's criteria.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81285/appropriate-measure-to-find-smallest-covariance-matrix/385902#385902   which also answers the question.

Answer (score 6):

Let $G$ and $H$ be positive definite, and let $v$ be any vector. Because the matrices are positive self definite, $\exists$ $a$ and $b$ such that $v^T G v = a >0$ and $v^T H v = b>0$.  Without loss of generality, assume $a \gt b$.  Then $H-G$ is not positive definite:
$$v^T(H-G)v^T = v^THv - v^TGv = b - a ≤ 0$$

Comment: I don}t think this is correct as written, because there do exist posdef $G,  H$ such that either $G-H$ or $H-G$ is posdef. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81285/appropriate-measure-to-find-smallest-covariance-matrix/385902#385902

Answer (score 3):

In general $H-G$ is not positive definite,  but $H-G$ will be positive definite  if we further assume the smallest singular  of $H$ is  larger than the  largest singular of $G$.  To  see this we let $H= U_1S_1V_1^T $ and  $G= U_2S_2V_2^T$  be the  svds  of $H$ and $ G$ respectively, and let x be arbitrary. Then

$|x^T H x| = |x^T(U_1S_1V_1^T)x| \geq |x^T min(\sigma_i(S_1)x|$

and

$|x^T G x| = |x^T(U_1S_2V_1^T)x| \leq |x^T max(\sigma_i(S_2))x| $