# Reference about the comparison between covariance matrices

Tags: references, covariance-matrix, intuition

Suppose we have 2 symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$.
Then, we say that $A \succeq B$ if $A - B$ is a positive semi-definite matrix.
I was wondering about the intuition and interpretation of $A \succeq B$, for example in terms of covariance matrices.
Then, I encountered [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81285/appropriate-measure-to-find-smallest-covariance-matrix/), which answered my question.

I was interested in the generalization of the comparison between variance matrices, presented by @Bill in his [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/391641/394663).
I was wondering if anyone would know any reference that supports his explanation about the comparison between covariance matrices.

To be more specific, suppose we have 2 random variables $a$ and $b$ with covariance matrix $\text{Cov}(a) = A$ and $\text{Cov}(b) = B$, respectively.
This [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/391641/394663) mentions a definition that $\text{Cov}(a) \geq \text{Cov}(b)$ if and only if $\text{Cov}(x^T a) \geq \text{Cov}(x^T b)$ for all vector $x$.
I want to know where I can find any reference that talks about this definition.
I am particularly interested in this because it gives a neat intuition on what $A \succeq B$ means.

Comment: See the Bhatia book referenced at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/385902/919.  The definitions are almost trivially equivalent: each immediately implies the other.