# Ellipse region shape from standard deviations

Tags: regression, bivariate

I need to draw a bivariate normal distribution ellipse based on [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0085253815585864). It says

> In the case of the bivariate normal distribution, both
>   approximate and exact methods are available for calculations of both
>   confidence and tolerance ellipses. We present our modified version of
>   the exact methods using common statistics of the simple linear correlation
>   analysis. Given n pairs of observations $x$ and $y$, with standard deviations $s_x$, and $s_y$, and correlation coefficient $r$, one must fix the $\alpha$ probability level and take the Snedecor's $F_\alpha$ value with 2 and $n-2$ degrees of freedom. The
>   semi-axes $L_1$ and $L_2$, and the slopes $b_1$ and $b_2 = -1/b_1$, of the axes of the
>   $100(1 — \alpha)\%$ confidence and tolerance ellipses can be calculated using
>   equations (1) and (2), respectively.
>
> $$
>     L_1, L_2 = K\sqrt{(n-1)({s_x}^2 + {s_y}^2) \pm \sqrt{[(n-1)({s_x}^2 + {s_y}^2)]^2 - 4(n-1)^2(1-r^2){s_x}^2 {s_y}^2}} \tag{Eq. 1}
> $$
>
> where
>
> $K = F/n(n-1)$ for confidence ellipses
>
> $K = F(n+1)/n(n-2)$ for tolerance ellipses
>
> $$
> b, -1/b = ({s_y}^2 - {s_x}^2)/2rs_xs_y \pm \sqrt{1 + [({s_y}^2 - {s_x}^2)/2rs_xs_y]^2} \tag{Eq. 2}
> $$

I won't have access to all the data points, only the means, standard deviations and $r$. But to test the equations I'm using the following data.

```
x = [19, 25, 22, -1, 4, 14, 21, 22, 23, 27, 29, 25, 29, 15, 29, 24, 0, 2, 26, 17, 19, 9, 20, -6, -13, -13, -11, -4, -4, 11, 23]
y = [28, 28, 26, 19, 16, 24, 26, 24, 24, 29, 29, 27, 31, 26, 38, 23, 13, 14, 28, 19, 19, 17, 22, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 14, 14, 23]
```

From this dataset I get

- $mean_x = 13$
- $mean_y = 20.226$
- $s_x = 13.619$
- $s_y = 8.808$
- $r = 0.924$

I'm using [this calculator](https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/f-distribution.aspx) (with the parameters $v_1$=2, $v_2$=29, cumulative prob=0.9) to get

$F_{90\%} = 2.5$

I'm calculating the following results in Clojure (that's very similar to Lisp), and here is the code I'm using to get them

```
(def F 2.5)

(def K (/ (* F (inc n))
          (* n (- n 2))))
```

- $K_{90\%} = 0.089$

```
(def Sx 13.619)
(def Sx2 (* Sx Sx))
(def Sy 8.808)
(def Sy2 (* Sy Sy))
(def r 0.924)
(def r2 (* r r))
(def n 31)

(def L1 (* k
           (Math/sqrt (+ (* (dec n) (+ Sx2 Sy2))
                         (Math/sqrt (- (Math/pow (* (dec n) (+ Sx2 Sy2)) 2)
                                       (* 4 (Math/pow (dec n) 2) (- 1 r2) Sx2 Sy2)))))))
```

- $L_1^{90\%} = 11.002$
- $L_2^{90\%} = 1.985$

```
(def b (+ (/ (- Sy2 Sx2)
             (* 2 r Sx Sy))
          (Math/sqrt (inc (Math/pow (/ (- Sy2 Sx2) (* 2 r Sx Sy)) 2)))))
```

- $b = 0.625$

This is drawing an ellipse like

[image: My wrong ellipse]

where I should get something like this

[image: The ellipse I should get]

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ellipse+%5Br%5D

Comment: I don't see an answer that fits to my case in this link.

Comment: I see many answers that *look* like they fit your case, so could you provide some additional comments that help us see how this is a different question?  On the surface, it looks like you have a bug in your code but you haven't supplied enough information to know any more than that.

Comment: I said I don't have the data points, I'm suppose to get the semi-axes from the standard deviations and the correlation r. I don't see another answer doing it. Is the value of F correct?

Comment: It would be difficult to draw such an ellipse *without* using the covariance matrix in the first place!  *Every* answer goes through that process, even if it begins with a dataset.  For instance, the [first hit in the search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9898) gives code that starts right off with the covariance matrix.

Comment: Yes, this is what my question is about. Aparently the article that I quoted explains how to draw such ellipse, but I must be doing something wrong in the step about the Snedecor's F value.

Comment: Perhaps--but could you show us how you are doing the calculations rather than just exhibiting the results? BTW, the formula you are applying is just an ugly way to represent a fundamentally simple operation (inversion of a $2\times 2$ matrix) and the equation of a circle, as explained in my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/62147/919.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104062/discussion-between-jp-and-whuber).

Answer (score 3):

[image: Ellipses drawn the right way]

It turned out that I lost a lot of time taking the article's formula too serious, it doesn't explain where the formula comes from. So I had to read a lot to understand the context and I'm providing some references for people who's not from maths or stats.

The interesting thing is that I can find $COV(x, y)$ (the covariance of $x$ and $y$) from the Standard Deviations $s_x$, $s_y$ and $r$ (Pearson Correlation Coeficient) as showed [here](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/correlationcoefficient.asp).

---

Therefore,

$COV(x, y) = COV(y, x) = s_xs_yr_{xy}$

$COV(x, x) = s_xs_x$

$COV(y, y) = s_ys_y$

$C_{xy} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
COV(x, x) & COV(x, y) \\
COV(y, x) & COV(y, y)
\end{bmatrix}$ (as showed [here](https://datascienceplus.com/understanding-the-covariance-matrix/))

I calculate the eigen values and eigen vectors [based](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/MtrxVibe/EigMat/MatrixEigen.html) [on](http://people.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math21b2004/exhibits/2dmatrices/index.html) [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#2.C3.972_matrices) [refs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395698/fast-way-to-calculate-eigen-of-2x2-matrix-using-a-formula).

```
(let [[[eigen-vec-1-x eigen-vec-2-x]
       [eigen-vec-1-y eigen-vec-2-y]] (eigen-vec c-xy)
      [eigen-val-x eigen-val-y]       (eigen-val c-xy)]))
```

I get the tolerance 50%, 80%, 90% and 95% based on [this table](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/tbl-chi.html) (with df=2).

```
(def tolerances (map chi-squared [0.5 0.8 0.9 0.95]))
```

The semi-axes and the slope are calculated using

```
(def x-axis (map #(Math/sqrt (* % eigen-val-x)) tolerances))
(def y-axis (map #(Math/sqrt (* % eigen-val-y)) tolerances))
(def slope  (Math/atan2 eigen-vec-1-x eigen-vec-1-y))
```

Some other useful references.

- https://waterprogramming.wordpress.com/2016/11/07/plotting-probability-ellipses-for-bivariate-normal-distributions/
- https://www.surveygizmo.com/resources/blog/variance-covariance-correlation/
- https://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/draw-error-ellipse-representing-covariance-matrix
- https://gist.github.com/CarstenSchelp/b992645537660bda692f218b562d0712#file-plot_confidence_ellipse-py-L44